# Resizing Rmarkdown gganimate plot

Tags: r, markdown, gganimate

I am hoping someone might know how to control the plot size at the bottom of this page:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwVoW6BAobRDY3hJaHpReDBrbmM

I am completely new to Rmarkdown.  I've played around with `fig.width` and `fig.height` to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

To your plot, add `+ coord_fixed()` to fix the aspect ratio. You can change the size of the GIF with `ani.width` and `ani.height`, so:

```
p <- p + coord.fixed()

gg_animate(p, 'output.gif', ani.width = 1000, ani.height = 1000)
```

Comment: that definitely helps but the plot ends up small relative to the legend.  Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Added some additional info. The arguments are passed to `saveGIF` in the [animation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html) package.